# Remove whitespace from an argument into a JS function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove whitespace from an argument passed by a HTML form into a function using the trim() method. The function then lists the addresses that match that postcode.

```
var postCodes = {
  N48LP: {
    address: ['59, White Gardens', '54, White Gardens', '52, White Gardens', '55, White Gardens']
  }
};

function searchCode(arg2){
  arg2.trim();
if(typeof postCodes[arg2] === 'undefined') {
  document.getElementById('oldpa').innerHTML = 'Postcode not found';
} else {
// code here which prints the list of addresses
     }}};
```

This doesn't work. Where 'N48LP' works, 'N4 8LP' or 'N 48LP' will result in 'Postcode not found'. Could anyone tell me why? Many thanks.

Comment: trim() removes only whitespace from beginning and end of string, not from the middle of it. Use split/join or regexps to remove all whitespaces if this is really what you want. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code. One is that [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) does not trim the string in-place, this means that it does not mutate the original string. The second one is that [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) does not remove spaces in between characters.

To solve this, you can use [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a regex that replaces all occurence of all spaces as empty strings, and then assign such value as an index to be used when checking the `postCodes` object.

```js
var postCodes = {
  N48LP: {
    address: ['59, White Gardens', '54, White Gardens', '52, White Gardens', '55, White Gardens']
  }
};

function searchCode(arg2) {
  // note that you have to make the regex to perform
  // a global search to make it function as a trim as well
  var index = arg2.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  if (typeof postCodes[index] === 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById('oldpa').innerHTML += 'Postcode not found';
  } else {
    // code here which prints the list of addresses
    document.getElementById('oldpa').innerHTML += [
      '<strong>input: ', arg2.replace(/\s+/g, '&nbsp;'), '</strong>',
      '<pre>', JSON.stringify(postCodes[index], 0, 4), '</pre>'
    ].join('');
  }
}

searchCode('N 48LP');
searchCode('  N48LP  ');
searchCode('  N 4 8 L P  ');
```

```html
<div id="oldpa"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try replace instead of trim.

```
arg2.replace(/\s+/, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

you are looking for: `arg2.split(' ').join('')`. `trim` function remove spaces from start and from end of strings only

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here `arg2.trim();`. As @DontRelaX said `trim()` methods does not remove white spaces in the middle of the string. And another problem, considering that this would be a problem, that `trim()` returns modified string, but does not effect the value of the sting [itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).